# Excel not display cell content

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I open an excel document, some of the cells are not displaying their data :

[image]

But the function box correctly displays the data contained within the cell :

[image]

I'm using version :

[image]

What can cause this ? I think I could use "format cells" to display the data but would prefer not to do this.

Comment: Typically, `######` is displayed when the column width isn't wide enough to show the content. Have you tried widening the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel treats dates and times as numbers. If Excel tries to display a number but the column isn't wide enough, it displays the "#####" text that you saw. You have a few choices:

1. Make the column wider until all data can be displayed
2. Format the cells to display the date/time in a different, shorter format
3. Add a column with a formula to display the date/time as text `=TEXT(A1,"m/d/yyyy hh:MM AM/PM")`

[image: Cell with long date/time]

[image: Cell with text date/time]

Note: If you just format the cell to be text, it'll display the number equivalent of the date/time which is probably not what you want.